# Signer Page Number

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to set the `<pageNumber>` to "last page" so the user will have to sign on the last page doesn't matter if the document is 5 pages or 10 pages long?

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="url">
<recipients>
<signers>
<signer>
<tabs>
<signHereTabs>
<signHere>
**<pageNumber>THIS ONE</pageNumber>**
</signHere>
</signHereTabs>
</tabs>
</signer>
</signers>
</recipients>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to you where to place signing tabs for your recipients by defining their location, size, and page numbers.  So if you know the how many pages are in the document then you can use that info to place tab(s) on that last page, however unless you have static content on that last page you'll want to be careful where you place your tab(s) so that they do not overlap important document info/content.

So for instance if you know that 100 pixels right and 100 pixels down from the top left of your document is a good area to place a signature tab, and let's say the last page is page 5 in this document, then you could use the following JSON to place on the last page:

```
"tabs": {
    "signHereTabs": [
        {
            "xPosition": "100",
            "yPosition": "100",
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "5"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you don't know how many pages are in your document(s), and hence you don't know what to set the pageNumber to, then the `Anchor Tagging` feature might be your savior here.  With `Anchor Tagging` you can specify the location of a given tab based on actual document content.

So for instance, if you know that on the last page of the document there will be the text "PLEASE SIGN HERE:", then you could tell the system to place any tab at or near that text in the document.  Furthermore you can offset the text (so that it doesn't overlap the actual content).  The below sample JSON shows how you would place a signature tab 1-inch to the right of the text "PLEASE SIGN HERE:"

```
"tabs": {
    "signHereTabs": [
        {
            "anchorString": "PlEASE SIGN HERE:",
            "anchorXOffset": "1",
            "anchorYOffset": "0",
            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
            "anchorUnits": "inches"
        }
    ]
}
```

For more info on Anchor Tagging please see this page from the DocuSign Developer Center (see the section titled **Tab Positioning**):

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to comment yes so I apologize for submitting my comment as an answer. @Ergin I tried sending the JSON you show in your answer but no signing tab is created in my document. I can get the sign tab to be created using the DocuSign interface and setting the same anchor text as I'm doing in my REST API call. Is there anything else I'm missing? Here is my JSON I'm sending to create my envelope (minus the document bytes). Maybe DS doesn't allow mixing anchor tabs and regular tabs?

```
{
   "Status":"sent",
   "EmailBlurb":"\u0027Forms from Michael G. Rudelson \u0026 Company\u0027 containing important information is ready for your review and eSignature. Please click on the View Documents button below to review and eSign the documents.",
   "EmailSubject":"Forms from John Doe \u0026 Company",
   "AllowReassign":false,
   "BrandId":null,
   "EnableWetSign":false,
   "Notification":{
      "UseAccountDefaults":true
   },
   "CustomFields":{
      "TextCustomFields":[
         {
            "Name":"EnvelopeId",
            "Required":false,
            "Show":false,
            "Value":"488"
         }
      ]
   },
   "Documents":[
      {
         "Name":"Form A",
         "DocumentId":1393
      },
      {
         "Name":"Form B",
         "DocumentId":1394
      },
      {
         "Name":"Form B with text tag",
         "DocumentId":1395
      }
   ],
   "Recipients":{
      "Signers":[
         {
            "Email":"chrisl91@email.com",
            "Name":"Chris",
            "ClientUserId":null,
            "RequireIdLookup":false,
            "RoutingOrder":1,
            "RecipientId":1479,
            "CustomFields":[
               "1479"
            ],
            "IdCheckConfigurationName":null,
            "Tabs":{
               "ApproveTabs":null,
               "CheckboxTabs":null,
               "CompanyTabs":null,
               "DateSignedTabs":[
                  {
                     "DocumentId":1393,
                     "PageNumber":1,
                     "RecipientId":1479,
                     "XPosition":394,
                     "YPosition":203,
                     "TabLabel":"Date Signed"
                  },
                  {
                     "AnchorText":"DocuSignDateSigned_C1A",
                     "AnchorXOffset":0,
                     "AnchorYOffset":0,
                     "AnchorUnits":null,
                     "AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":true
                  },
                  {
                     "AnchorText":"DocuSignDateSigned_C1A",
                     "AnchorXOffset":0,
                     "AnchorYOffset":0,
                     "AnchorUnits":null,
                     "AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":true
                  }
               ],
               "DateTabs":null,
               "DeclineTabs":null,
               "EmailTabs":null,
               "EnvelopeIdTabs":null,
               "FullNameTabs":null,
               "InitialHereTabs":[

               ],
               "ListTabs":null,
               "NoteTabs":null,
               "NumberTabs":null,
               "RadioGroupTabs":null,
               "SignHereTabs":[
                  {
                     "DocumentId":1393,
                     "PageNumber":1,
                     "RecipientId":1479,
                     "XPosition":70,
                     "YPosition":172,
                     "TabLabel":"Sign Here"
                  },
                  {
                     "AnchorText":"DocuSignSignHere_C1A",
                     "AnchorXOffset":0,
                     "AnchorYOffset":0,
                     "AnchorUnits":null,
                     "AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":true
                  },
                  {
                     "AnchorText":"DocuSignSignHere_C1A",
                     "AnchorXOffset":0,
                     "AnchorYOffset":0,
                     "AnchorUnits":null,
                     "AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent":true
                  }
               ],
               "SignerAttachmentTabs":null,
               "SsnTabs":null,
               "TextTabs":null,
               "TitleTabs":null,
               "ZipTabs":null
            },
            "IdCheckInformationInput":null
         },
         {
            "Email":"c@email.com",
            "Name":"Jim Doe",
            "ClientUserId":null,
            "RequireIdLookup":false,
            "RoutingOrder":2,
            "RecipientId":1480,
            "CustomFields":[
               "1480"
            ],
            "IdCheckConfigurationName":null,
            "Tabs":{
               "ApproveTabs":null,
               "CheckboxTabs":null,
               "CompanyTabs":null,
               "DateSignedTabs":[
                  {
                     "DocumentId":1393,
                     "PageNumber":1,
                     "RecipientId":1480,
                     "XPosition":394,
                     "YPosition":503,
                     "TabLabel":"Date Signed"
                  }
               ],
               "DateTabs":null,
               "DeclineTabs":null,
               "EmailTabs":null,
               "EnvelopeIdTabs":null,
               "FullNameTabs":null,
               "InitialHereTabs":[

               ],
               "ListTabs":null,
               "NoteTabs":null,
               "NumberTabs":null,
               "RadioGroupTabs":null,
               "SignHereTabs":[
                  {
                     "DocumentId":1393,
                     "PageNumber":1,
                     "RecipientId":1480,
                     "XPosition":70,
                     "YPosition":472,
                     "TabLabel":"Sign Here"
                  }
               ],
               "SignerAttachmentTabs":null,
               "SsnTabs":null,
               "TextTabs":null,
               "TitleTabs":null,
               "ZipTabs":null
            },
            "IdCheckInformationInput":null
         }
      ],
      "CarbonCopies":[
         {
            "Email":"c@email.com",
            "Name":"Jim Doe as CC",
            "ClientUserId":null,
            "RequireIdLookup":false,
            "RoutingOrder":1,
            "RecipientId":99999,
            "CustomFields":[
               "99999"
            ],
            "IdCheckConfigurationName":null,
            "Tabs":{
               "ApproveTabs":null,
               "CheckboxTabs":null,
               "CompanyTabs":null,
               "DateSignedTabs":[

               ],
               "DateTabs":null,
               "DeclineTabs":null,
               "EmailTabs":null,
               "EnvelopeIdTabs":null,
               "FullNameTabs":null,
               "InitialHereTabs":[

               ],
               "ListTabs":null,
               "NoteTabs":null,
               "NumberTabs":null,
               "RadioGroupTabs":null,
               "SignHereTabs":[

               ],
               "SignerAttachmentTabs":null,
               "SsnTabs":null,
               "TextTabs":null,
               "TitleTabs":null,
               "ZipTabs":null
            },
            "IdCheckInformationInput":null
         }
      ]
   },
   "EmailSettings":{
      "ReplyEmailAddressOverride":"c@email.com",
      "ReplyEmailNameOverride":"Jim Doe",
      "BccEmailAddresses":null
   }
}
```

Comment: I noticed I added duplicate anchor tabs but I just removed the dupe and it still is not adding a signing tab based on anchor text.